# resizing a UITableViewCell frame issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to resize my `UITableViewCell's` frame via:

```
 [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, 
                           cell.frame.origin.y, 
                           cell.frame.size.width, 
                           cell.frame.size.height+25)];
```

however, it's not resizing after I do this... why is this?

This is weird as if I add a `UIToolBar` into the cell, it resizes but when I am adding a UIView, it doesn't:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:sideSwipeView];
```

Comment: Hi aherlambang... Did the answers help? Please select the answer that was correct... If not, please comment to let us know how it was not helpful. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the long and short of it:

1. Your cell width is determined by the width of the tableview it's in.

[EDIT: If it's a grouped table view, the cell is 20 - 60 pixels narrower than the tableview width, depending if you're using an iPhone, or an iPad.]

2. Your cell height is determined by the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

If you're manually setting the cell's frame, it's going to be useless except when you're using a subclassed cell where you want to add subviews based on the cell's dimensions.

Even in this case, it's recommended to get the cell's frame from the tableview by using `rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` method and then setting that frame as the cell's frame (after setting the frame's origin Y as 0).

I'm not quite sure about the UIToolBar, but your subview's frame won't change on changing the cell frame.

Maybe if you could tell us what you're trying to achieve, we can suggest a solution for you?

**--------------------EDIT--------------------**

So you need to dynamically add a subview to a cell on tapping it and resize it's height according to the new subview. This is gonna get hairy so here goes:

In your .h file declare:

```
BOOL subviewAdded;
```

In your .m file, in the init, do:

```
subviewAdded = NO;
```

Let's assume that you want the cell's height to be 50 without the subview and 100 with the subview. Accordingly, your heightForRow method should be:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return (subviewAdded?100.0f:50.0f);
}
```

This means that initially since subviewAdded is NO, all your cells will have the smaller height.

Now, to add a subview to a cell on tapping it, and to change it's height dynamically, do this in your didSelectRow method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Get the cell at this indexPath

    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(subviewAdded)
    {
        subviewAdded = NO;

        for(int i = 0; i < [thisCell.contentView.subviews count]; i++)
        {
            UIView *thisSubview = [thisCell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            [thisSubview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];

        [thisCell.contentView addSubview:someView];
        [someView release];

        subviewAdded = YES;
    }

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]; 

    [array addObject:indexPath];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array 
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

So what's going to happen here is you're adding a subview to this cell you've tapped. Reloading this cell will call `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and do a nice little fade animation and change your tableview heights.

IMPORTANT: Ideally, you should maintain an array of NSNumbers with boolean values. The array size should be the same size as the number of tableview cells you have.

In heightForRow, you would then check against this array instead of using a single boolean for the whole tableView. This would ensure that you could have different heights for different cells.

That would look something like:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL thisBool = (BOOL)[[booleanArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

    return (thisBool?100.0f:50.0f);
}
```

I didn't post all that code here since it's implied and what I've posted should put you well on your way to doing the boolean array thing.

Anyway, there you are. I just tested this code myself so it works :)

Comment: I am trying to create http://thenextweb.com/apps/files/2011/04/iPhone-Screenshot-11.jpeg, where if you tap the cell once it adds a subview to the cell and tap it again it removes the subview.. all adjusting the view height dynamically

Answer (score 5):

If you want to increase the height of your cell based on some parameter eg. text, image, 
you must implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method of  `UITableViewDelegate`  in your code.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: +1 The table doesn't ask the cell about it's dimensions when it lays them out. For better or worse, that just isn't how it works.

Comment: I am very well aware of it, however now the issue is that when I do a check inside heightForRowAtIndexPath whether this subviews exists or not, so I can adjust the height it crashes. I just added this code if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:5] != nil)
        optionsHeight = 25;.

Comment: heightForRow is called BEFORE cellForRow.... hence the crash. Your cell doesn't "exist" yet. In heightForRow you're telling the tableview to render the cell to a specific height. It hasn't rendered the cell at this point so you can't access the cell.

Comment: then how is it possible then to use this?? I need the cell first to determine the height, I can't just specify it here the height as it is dynamic and depends whether a particular view or not exists in the cell... any solutions to this? This subview is added later on during runtime...

Comment: @Siddharth Iyer : Please read the documentation carefully, i could not understand accessing of cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath as you mentioned ,you never need to access in heightForRowAtIndexPath, just return the height for that cell.  @aherlambang :All you table with variable cell height as you see in others application,are implemented by this manner. Go with it, if you require any assistance let me know.

Comment: @aherlambang : Cell height is calculated by its content (text, images, other views). and you could access these (text, images, other views)in heightForRowAtIndexPath, and calculate the exact height.

Comment: @Jhaliya : If you read my comment carefully, I do mention "It hasn't rendered the cell at this point so you can't access the cell." I wasn't commenting on your answer.... I was replying to aherlambang's comment before mine. I was explaining WHY the crash occurred when he tried what he did. Probably should have had an @aherlambang before that comment.

Comment: @ Siddharth Iyer : No offense friend, I made the comment for your answer not for your comment on my answer, As i read now your are correct with your answer.